# How do you add a profile specification to a FirefoxDriverService in C# Selenium?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, clearscript

Context: Azure, C#, ClearScript, Selenium, Firefox

I'm exposing Selenium's Firefox symbols into a ClearScript JavaScript environment. In the following JavaScript code, the symbols exposed/exported from C# are prefixed with CS.

```
// Preamble_LaunchBrowser.js
driverService = CSFirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.FirefoxBinaryPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
driverService.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
var options = new CSFirefoxOptions();
driver = new CSFirefoxDriver(driverService, options, CSTimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
driver.Url = "http://www.google.com.au/";
```

At present I have no support for profiles, but would like to add them somehow. How would I specify a profile in the context of a FirefoxDriverService?

Answer (score 1):

> At present I have no support for profiles, but would like to add them somehow. How would I specify a profile in the context of a FirefoxDriverService?

Forgive me if I'm missing the point.

Just start up FireFox with this command line `firefox.exe -p` to create a new profile.

Then when you run your javascript, run it in FireFox under the newly created profile.

Comment: That works on the command line. However I'm talking to firefox via Selenium. I can't see `driverService.FirefoxBinaryPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe -p profilename";` working.

Comment: Yeah I don't see it working creating a FF profile via Selenium hence my suggestion create the profiles and run your code under the user profile

Comment: Did you try it though? creating a profile and starting it with the `-p profilename`?